# Will my luggage be sent to my final destination if book separate sector tickets?

Tags: transit, luggage, connecting-flights, dxb

I'm planning a family trip to Armenia (Yerevan) from Riyadh.

Option 1- FlyDubai's booking engine is showing an error if I book RUH-EVN-DXB-RUH on a particular date.

Option 2- If I do it as RUH-DXB-EVN-DXB-RUH, the booking goes smoothly and there is no cost difference.

If I check my luggage in Riyadh, by using Option 2, will I need to re-check my baggage in Dubai? I do not intend to leave the airport, and the connecting flight is exactly the same as Option 1.

Guidance needed by travel gurus and people who have experienced situations like this.

Comment: what's a sector ticket?

Answer (score 2):

It's debatable and might come down to the agent at the desk.

Technically if you book on separate tickets (defined by having two different PNRs - the 6 digit bookings reference), then they're usually treated as separate for everything. Can't check luggage, etc etc.

Also, if you fly on different airlines on these tickets, then very likely you'll need to pick up luggage part way.

However, I've had success on different PNRs with the same airline, managing to get them checked through.

A risky failsafe is when I was in Almaty airport and realised I didn't have a visa to get out, and my luggage wasn't checked through to the next one - ground staff were able to go out for me, identify my bag, and check it back in.  I presume this might be a not-uncommon experience, especially in such a high traffic airport like Dubai.  But planning around that would be risky.